# How to store files users upload on website?

Tags: database, upload, filesystems, storage, server

If a user is going to be uploading files to my website how should I store them. Should I just chuck it all in the server and create a folder with the user's username that contain all their files?

Are there any tutorials you would recommend that explains how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a vague question in my opinion and highly dependent on your **infrastructure**, **OS**, **storage type** and **storage location** and the **data types** you will be storing. It also depends on the **amount** of data that your application will be handling and the amount of **I/O**s to disk that you will be doing.

I'm going to continue with a vague assumption that you will be using S3 buckets to satisfy your purposes and would recommend going over [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/) by Jeff Bar. The article discusses a few performance tips and tricks for using Amazon S3 which can be helpful in more general scenarios/environments.

Comment: Yea so basically what I'm asking is if my website allows users to upload files how do I store them?

Comment: @KevinShen your question is still not describing your need. What do you mean by 'how do I store them'? The article referenced explains one of the many strategies to adopt in storing files.